# CSS Flexbox Separate Columns

Tags: css, flexbox, word-wrap

I have built a very basic responsive web page here:

https://codepen.io/beckytownsend/pen/wqaoRR

I want to split the main content into who sections, paragraphs on the left and the sidebar on the right when it expands past 1200px, like so..

P= paragraph, S= Sidebar

P  S
P

I also want the two section to sit in the center of the page. I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work! Please could someone have a look at my code and let me know what I can do?

```css
.main-content{
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
 
 /*Paragraphs within main content*/
  .paragraph {
  float:left;
  width: 60%;
  order: 1;
 flex-direction: column;
}

  /*Sidebar*/
.sidebar {
background: teal;
 float: right;
 width: 30%;
 order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
<div class="paragraph">
  <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor. </h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nisl est, mollis at risus vel, aliquam molestie sapien. Mauris in nunc ut enim semper vestibulum ut at sapien. Integer eu commodo nunc, et porta justo. Mauris vel sapien nulla. Maecenas ullamcorper facilisis velit ut imperdiet. Integer at elit et turpis lobortis varius. Pellentesque malesuada eros vel tempus feugiat.

Sed ex leo, pulvinar nec elit sit amet, feugiat ullamcorper diam. Phasellus ipsum risus, malesuada non euismod et, vulputate sit amet ligula. Suspendisse sed vestibulum diam. Donec eget nulla vitae ex ultrices pulvinar. Suspendisse dui sem, cursus sit amet aliquam eu, elementum vitae ipsum. In imperdiet, dolor non vehicula porttitor, risus est lobortis erat, at vehicula mauris sapien eget risus. Maecenas id enim volutpat, congue odio nec, ultricies mauris. Nulla ornare urna ac eros sodales vulputate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div class="paragraph">
  <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor. </h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nisl est, mollis at risus vel, aliquam molestie sapien. Mauris in nunc ut enim semper vestibulum ut at sapien. Integer eu commodo nunc, et porta justo. Mauris vel sapien nulla. Maecenas ullamcorper facilisis velit ut imperdiet. Integer at elit et turpis lobortis varius. Pellentesque malesuada eros vel tempus feugiat.
<br><br>
Sed ex leo, pulvinar nec elit sit amet, feugiat ullamcorper diam. Phasellus ipsum risus, malesuada non euismod et, vulputate sit amet ligula. Suspendisse sed vestibulum diam. Donec eget nulla vitae ex ultrices pulvinar. Suspendisse dui sem, cursus sit amet aliquam eu, elementum vitae ipsum. In imperdiet, dolor non vehicula porttitor, risus est lobortis erat, at vehicula mauris sapien eget risus. Maecenas id enim volutpat, congue odio nec, ultricies mauris. Nulla ornare urna ac eros sodales vulputate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<br><br>
Curabitur leo enim, feugiat sed ligula in, laoreet lobortis dui. In semper porta nibh ut scelerisque. Nam commodo sapien in nisi tempor, vel dignissim nisl gravida. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse mattis urna quis arcu vehicula lacinia. Fusce convallis lorem vitae scelerisque ullamcorper. Vivamus vel est nec diam iaculis cursus non in lacus. Proin eu libero sed urna vehicula.
<br><br>
 Proin accumsan, velit id commodo blandit, odio felis dictum diam, ut tempor lacus metus non dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus viverra lectus rutrum tristique feugiat. Etiam sit amet mi vel neque fringilla viverra at sit amet risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In et turpis vestibulum, aliquam ex vel, imperdiet felis. Nam luctus velit nulla. Praesent tempor dignissim magna vel euismod. In auctor gravida nibh, ut facilisis dui tincidunt bibendum. Aliquam et nisi ac velit consectetur dapibus. Fusce consectetur semper mauris eu tempus. Aenean leo tortor, interdum quis pharetra at, varius vel orci. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. Sed ligula nunc, consequat nec purus non, volutpat egestas mauris.
</p>
</div>


<div class="sidebar">
 
  <h3> Lorem ipsum </h3>
  <p>Quisque hendrerit metus id justo congue hendrerit non in libero. Phasellus quis enim vel sem sagittis eleifend. Aenean gravida, metus id pharetra imperdiet, nibh risus vestibulum lacus, nec gravida felis arcu id tortor. Donec id lectus eu enim accumsan aliquam. Etiam nunc arcu, volutpat quis erat vel, rhoncus condimentum nunc. Integer pulvinar lectus non pulvinar iaculis. Maecenas lorem libero, egestas ac mi ac, hendrerit commodo sapien. Cras finibus sem neque, in mollis eros facilisis eget. Quisque id lacus aliquam, tristique est id, facilisis nulla. Donec vitae faucibus nunc.</p>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you want the two sections to sit in the center of the page vertically or horizontally? or both..

Comment: Why are you not actually using separete div to divide into columns. It's unlcear to me what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the paragraphs in a new container and give that the following:

```
.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

You can then remove all the `flexbox` properties from the paragraph. Note that `float` does not work in a flex container.

```css
.main-content {
  justify-content: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-right: 50px;
}


/*Sidebar*/

.sidebar {
  background: teal;
  min-width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="paragraph">
      <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor. </h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nisl est, mollis at risus vel, aliquam molestie sapien. Mauris in nunc ut enim semper vestibulum ut at sapien. Integer eu commodo nunc, et porta justo. Mauris vel sapien nulla.
        Maecenas ullamcorper facilisis velit ut imperdiet. Integer at elit et turpis lobortis varius. Pellentesque malesuada eros vel tempus feugiat. Sed ex leo, pulvinar nec elit sit amet, feugiat ullamcorper diam. Phasellus ipsum risus, malesuada non
        euismod et, vulputate sit amet ligula. Suspendisse sed vestibulum diam. Donec eget nulla vitae ex ultrices pulvinar. Suspendisse dui sem, cursus sit amet aliquam eu, elementum vitae ipsum. In imperdiet, dolor non vehicula porttitor, risus est
        lobortis erat, at vehicula mauris sapien eget risus. Maecenas id enim volutpat, congue odio nec, ultricies mauris. Nulla ornare urna ac eros sodales vulputate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="paragraph">
      <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor. </h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nisl est, mollis at risus vel, aliquam molestie sapien. Mauris in nunc ut enim semper vestibulum ut at sapien. Integer eu commodo nunc, et porta justo. Mauris vel sapien nulla.
        Maecenas ullamcorper facilisis velit ut imperdiet. Integer at elit et turpis lobortis varius. Pellentesque malesuada eros vel tempus feugiat.
        <br><br> Sed ex leo, pulvinar nec elit sit amet, feugiat ullamcorper diam. Phasellus ipsum risus, malesuada non euismod et, vulputate sit amet ligula. Suspendisse sed vestibulum diam. Donec eget nulla vitae ex ultrices pulvinar. Suspendisse dui
        sem, cursus sit amet aliquam eu, elementum vitae ipsum. In imperdiet, dolor non vehicula porttitor, risus est lobortis erat, at vehicula mauris sapien eget risus. Maecenas id enim volutpat, congue odio nec, ultricies mauris. Nulla ornare urna
        ac eros sodales vulputate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        <br><br> Curabitur leo enim, feugiat sed ligula in, laoreet lobortis dui. In semper porta nibh ut scelerisque. Nam commodo sapien in nisi tempor, vel dignissim nisl gravida. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse mattis urna quis arcu vehicula lacinia.
        Fusce convallis lorem vitae scelerisque ullamcorper. Vivamus vel est nec diam iaculis cursus non in lacus. Proin eu libero sed urna vehicula.
        <br><br> Proin accumsan, velit id commodo blandit, odio felis dictum diam, ut tempor lacus metus non dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus viverra lectus rutrum tristique feugiat. Etiam sit amet mi vel neque fringilla viverra at sit
        amet risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In et turpis vestibulum, aliquam ex vel, imperdiet felis. Nam luctus velit nulla. Praesent tempor dignissim magna vel euismod. In auctor gravida
        nibh, ut facilisis dui tincidunt bibendum. Aliquam et nisi ac velit consectetur dapibus. Fusce consectetur semper mauris eu tempus. Aenean leo tortor, interdum quis pharetra at, varius vel orci. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. Sed ligula nunc,
        consequat nec purus non, volutpat egestas mauris.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">

    <h3> Lorem ipsum </h3>
    <p>Quisque hendrerit metus id justo congue hendrerit non in libero. Phasellus quis enim vel sem sagittis eleifend. Aenean gravida, metus id pharetra imperdiet, nibh risus vestibulum lacus, nec gravida felis arcu id tortor. Donec id lectus eu enim accumsan
      aliquam. Etiam nunc arcu, volutpat quis erat vel, rhoncus condimentum nunc. Integer pulvinar lectus non pulvinar iaculis. Maecenas lorem libero, egestas ac mi ac, hendrerit commodo sapien. Cras finibus sem neque, in mollis eros facilisis eget. Quisque
      id lacus aliquam, tristique est id, facilisis nulla. Donec vitae faucibus nunc.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is much better! How would I amend it so that the sidebar is at the top inline with the first paragraph, but still to the right? I'm very new to this so am still a bit confused by it all.

Comment: use `align-self:flex-start;` to align with first paragraph.

Comment: @BeckyTownsend Remove `align-items` rule from `.main-content` -- I'll update answer...